# C++ ranges how to create a std::map

Tags: c++

Is there a way in the c++ ranges library to create a map. Lets say I have a range of integers and I want to create a std::map with the square of each one, in pseudo code

```
vect<int> x { 1, 3, 5, 10 }

map<int,int> y = // magic happens here using x

y == std::map<int,int> { { 1, 1 }, { 3, 9 }, { 5, 25 }, { 10, 100 } };
```

For those of you that are C# LINQ users, I am looking for an equivalent to ToDictionary

Answer
Out of band someone suggested the following

```
vector<int> x { 1, 3, 5, 10 };
auto const squares = 
    ranges::views::zip( x, x | ranges::views::transform( []( int i ) { return i * i; } ) ) | 
    ranges::to<std::map<int,int>>( );
```

which is pretty awesome. Note I am using VS 2019 16.5 Preview 2 with Range V3 0.9.1 via VCPKG in case it doesn't compile for others. Now if only understood how it really works!!!

Comment: Please don't edit your question to include an answer. It's perfectly acceptable and encouraged even to answer your own question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use std::transform

```
std::vector<int> myVec{ 1, 3, 5, 10 };
std::map<int, int> myMap;
std::transform(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), std::inserter(myMap, myMap.end()),
    [](const int &val) { return std::make_pair(val, pow(val,2)); });
```

It's not an on-assignment one-liner but it's pretty clean.

Comment: I've never really been a fan of using code like that when the equivalent range for loop is about the same amount of code. To me if your going to use a more complicated idiom like std::transform it should make the code simpler/shorter/easier to read/...